Observations on Pythagorean Triplets using one variable
We start with the well-known equations for generating Pythagorean triplets:
$
a = 2n + 1, \quad b = 2n^2 + 2n, \quad c = 2n^2 + 2n + 1
$
where $n$ is a positive integer.
By substituting $n$ with a fraction $\frac{g}{h}$ and scaling up by a factor of $h^2$, we ensure that the resulting values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all integers. This scaling technique allows us to obtain all possible Pythagorean triplets.
$
a = 2gh + h^2, \quad b = 2g^2 + 2gh, \quad c = 2g^2 + 2gh + h^2
$
We also introduce the variable $x$ into our equations by replacing $n$ with $\frac{g}{h}$ and expressing $\tan x$ as $\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}$. This enables us to explore Pythagorean triplets using trigonometric functions.
Furthermore, scaling up by a factor of $\cos^2 x$ ensures that the resulting values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ are "integer" representations except for irrational values.
$
a = 2sin(x)cos(x) + cos^2(x), \quad b = 2sin^2(x) + 2sin(x)cos(x), \quad c = 2sin^2(x) + 2sin(x)cos(x) + cos^2(x)
$
lets say $tan(x)= 1, \frac{g}{h} = 1,g=h $, this encodes a primitive Pythagorean triplet and triplets that are related. $tan(x)= \frac{g}{h}= 1$ encodes $ [1/1 \Rightarrow (3,4,5),2/2 \Rightarrow (12,16,20),3/3\Rightarrow(27,36,45)...]$
Upon plotting the graph of $a$, $b$, and $c$ in terms of $x$, we observe that the highest and lowest points of the sine waves relate to the golden ratio. This intriguing observation suggests a deeper connection between trigonometric functions and the properties of Pythagorean triplets. Any ideas why the golden ratio appears?
a,b,c sine waves
CHATGPT helped me express and translate this document

The above parametrization is not the standard way to generate Pythagorean triples. It is a special case of the parametrization $a=m^2-n^2$ , $b=2mn$ , $c=m^2+n^2$. $m=n+1$ leads to the given parametrization. Hard to believe that ChatGPT is good for something :)

$a,b,c$ in terms of $x$ never get bigger than $3,4,5$, respectively, so I'm not impressed with this "connection" between trig functions and Pythagorean triples.

Just exactly how do the highest and lowest points of the sine waves relate to the golden ratio?

I'm pretty sure you can also generate Pythagorean triplets using the 'g,h' method as described above. ChatGPT was ok at generating an outline.

tan(x) can output any number from 0-infinity. I know a,b,c in terms of x doesn't make big triangles but stores information them.  Let tan(x)= 4/3, sin(x)= 4/5, cos(x)=3/5 and we get small a,b,c's but if we instead translate them to our g=4, h=3 equations we get a=33, b=56, c=65.

a_max= (1+5^1/2)/2    a_min(1-5^1/2)/2 (golden ratios), b_max= (1+2^1/2) b_min(1-2^1/2), c_max=a_max+1 c_min=a_min+1 (golden ratios+1). 'a' and 'c' are more related to the golden ratio than 'b'

You should know that with $t=\tan \frac{\theta}2$ the formulae $x=\cos \theta =\frac {1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $y=\sin \theta = \frac {2t}{1+t^2}$ give a rational parametrisation of the unit circle from which the Pythagorean triples can be derived by chosing $t$ rational and clearing fractions. This is the most straightforward link between pythagorean triples and the trigonometric functions.

I did not make that connection :( Getting the extremes for each a,b,c functions is just a little bit of calculus after subbing sin(x),cos(x) with the 't' format right? Still pretty cool seeing any rational number 't' mapping to a pythagorean triplet when converted to 'g,h' integers.
